# C program to check_order not working properly

Tags: c, loops

Im using online GeeksforGeeks for learning how to code. I just started learning but for some reason the compiler return garbage when the sum of my input exceeds 3616. Can any pro please explain to me why and how to improve my code?

Eg. input: 1 2 3 4 5 0 output:increasing order  //sum of input< 3616

input: 1 2 3614 0  output:not increasing order //sum of input> 3616

This was the question:

Write a program check_order.c to read in a list of positive integers. The program is to continue asking for the next positive integer as long as the integers entered are in increasing order. The moment the input data are not in increasing order, or the input value is zero, the input ends. The program should then report whether the input data are in increasing order or not.
You may assume that at least one positive integer will be entered. If there is only one positive integer in the list, we will treat the list as it is in increasing order.
You may write all the code in the main() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(void){
    int input, input2;
    do{
        input2 = input;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("Enter positive integer: %d\n", input);
    }

    while(input> input2);

    if(input< input2){
        if(input == 0){
            printf("Data are in increasing order.");  
        }
        else{
            printf("Data are not in increasing order.");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Data are in increasing order.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Resolved. thanks all!!! :)

Comment: `input2 = input;` invokes Undefined Behavior as in the first iteration, `input` hasn't been initialized

Comment: You have a flaw in your validation of the input. In the first iteration of the loop `input` is not initialized, it will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. After the assignment `input2` will also have this indeterminate value. That means your comparison in the loop condition is incorrect.

Comment: omg i love you all, that solves the 3616 limit.

Comment: The loop `do{..) while(input> input2);` will not end unless the data is not in increasing order. You should check for an input that represents end of input.

Comment: @Adder 0 is such an input...

Comment: *Im using online GeeksforGeeks for learning how to code.* -- Stop! Get a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't initialize input it gets a garbage value. it can be positive or negative- and you can never know which value. To avoid that situation, you have to give an initialize value, so you can almost always be in fully control on your variables. It is alway recommended to set an initialize value to your variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {
    int input = 0, input2;
    do {
        input2 = input;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("Enter positive integer: %d\n", input);
    }
    while(input > input2);
    if (input < input2) {
        if(input == 0) {
            printf("Data are in increasing order.");  
        }
        else {
        printf("Data are not in increasing order.");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Data are in increasing order.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```